# Give me a blank Comment box when I am Improving a Suggested Edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edit-summary

The suggested edit screen includes both the suggested edit, and the reason for the edit:

> [image: Right above the question itself in the review, you'll find the reason given for the edit.]

When you click to improve the edit, that comment is left as-is and hidden at the bottom of the post above the save edit button:

> [image: The edit summary is already filled out with that reason.]

At the moment, when I Improve a Suggested Edit, the Comment text for that Edit is retained (though editable). It's unlikely that the comment would still apply (e.g. Suggester added a tag and Approver corrected a typo), so I would rather have the field blank.

Also, it's better to have a blank Comment than an incorrect one... many people don't bother changing the original Comment.

So that box should be blank like this instead:

> [image: (the edit summary no longer has the original reason filled out already, it's just empty)]

Comment: Oh, you mean the comment that accompanies the Suggested Edit, where you explain why you're making the suggested edit, right?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I tried to clarify

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added screenshots to better explain the issue as I understand it (someone just needs to approve the edit). Let me know if this isn't correct Tshepang!

Comment: I agree with the OP, but maybe I'm using improve wrong? If I see an edit that is too minor, but feel like improving it, the origional edit summary isn't applicable anymore most of the time. Especially if a big issue is overlooked. The final edit summary must reflect the actual edit, not the origional one, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Nanne I am reasonably certain that the issue isn't that Tshepang disagrees (chances are he fully agrees the text *should* match the edit), but rather than due to the design (shifting the reason from the top to the bottom, and leaving the previous text in it) makes it easy to overlook, and makes it far more likely to leave the previous text in. In the absence of a proper description, blank is better than a misleading description after all.