# "Improve edit" should not copy the edit summary from the suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits, edit-summary

When you click the "Improve edit" button when reviewing a suggested edit, your edit will be applied as a separate edit on top of the suggested edit, which will be approved.  The edit summary for your edit is pre-filled with the edit summary of the suggested edit that you are improving on.

This is *almost never* desirable: the edit summary of the suggested edit describes what was *already* done by the suggested edit.  Since you're making additional changes on top of that, you're almost certainly doing something different.

In addition to being unclear to new reviewers (when I encountered it as a new reviewer, I left it because I thought if I changed it, I would be changing it for the suggested edit), I still often forget to change it, resulting in edit summaries that inaccurately describe my edit.

Instead, **it should leave the edit summary field blank**, which would fill it with the default auto-generated edit descriptions if not changed.

Comment: This is already requested: [Give me a blank Comment box when I am Improving a Suggested Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198201/give-me-a-blank-comment-box-when-i-am-improving-a-suggested-edit)

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog dang it, I searched, too, just with the wrong keywords...thanks for the link, I'll go support that one :-)